# regex to strip all html tags except span tag

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to remove all the html from a string except

`<span class="match">...text...</span>`

Suppose if a string is `"<p>Hello  there</p><span class="match">wassup</span>"`

I just need `"Hello  there<span class="match">wassup</span>"`

Can anybody help? I am doing it in ruby (rails)

Comment: A regex is not your answer. If you're trying to strip HTML because you're going to show it on a page later, using a regex will eventually bite you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege

Comment: Consider `<p>Hello <!-- </p> --> there</p>`

Comment: ya... I used the sanitize helper as suggested by chris... i was using gsub to strip all the html tags before... so i thought i could use some regexp...

Comment: Duplicate of the Cthulhu question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ActionView::Helpers provides the `sanitize` method to do this.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize

```
sanitize "some html", :tags => %w"span"
```